# make one field as mandatory in two fields in django forms

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have the form field like this

so

how to make only one field as mandatory  either hi or bye.  Need at least one field as mandatory and another can optional while submitting the form django

```
 class MeForm(forms.Form):
        hi = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
        by = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override `clean` method for this:

```
class MeForm(forms.Form):
    hi = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False)
    by = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False)

    def clean(self):
        hi = self.cleaned_data.get('hi')
        by = self.cleaned_data.get('by')
        if not hi and not by:
            raise forms.ValidationError('One of fields is required')
        return self.cleaned_data
```

Comment: python 2.7 doesn't support  super without args

Comment: i added please check sir

Comment: def post(self,request):
        form = MeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid(): if ===> false?????????/

Comment: @HemanthSP yes if form is not valid you should return: `render(request, "template.html", {"form": form})`

Comment: yes i written that but still i have to enter two fields

Comment: @HemanthSP oh, add also `required=False` to the fields. Check updates.

Comment: and how to output ('One of fields is required') error in html

Comment: @HemanthSP You need to add `{{ form.non_field_errors }}`. Check this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually

Comment: in need to trim white spaces , which is the best way for my example